# Need help in Web scraping webpages and its links by automatic funciton in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-analysis

I am interested to extract the data of paranormal activity reported in news, so that i can analyze the 
data of space and time of appearance for any correlations. This project is just for fun, to learn and use web scraping, text extraction and spatial and time correlation analysis. So please forgive me for deciding on this topic, I wanted to do something interesting and challenging work.
First I found this website has some collection of the reported paranormal incidences, they have collection for 2009,2010,2011 and 2012.
The structure of the website goes like this in every year they have 1..10 pages...and links goes like this
for year2009
link http://paranormal.about.com/od/paranormalgeneralinfo/tp/2009-paranormal-activity.htm

In each page they have collected the stories under the heading like this
Internal structure
Paranormal Activity, Posted 03-14-09
each of these head lines has two pages inside it..goes like this
link http://paranormal.about.com/od/paranormalgeneralinfo/a/news_090314n.htm

On each of these pages they have actual reported stories collected on various headlines..and the actual websites link for those stories. I am interested in collecting those reported text and extract information regarding the kind of paranormal activity like ghost, demon or UFOs and  the time, date and place of incidents. I wish to analyze this data for any spatial and time correlations. If UFO or Ghosts are real they must have some behavior and correlations in space or time in their movements. This is long shot of the story...

***I need help in web scraping the text form the above said pages. Here i have wrote down the code to follow one page and its link down to last final text i want. Can anyone let me know is there any better and efficient way to get the clean text from the final page. Also automation of the collecting text by following all 10 pages for whole 2009.***

```
library(XML)
#source of paranormal news from about.com
#first page to start
#2009 -  http://paranormal.about.com/od/paranormalgeneralinfo/tp/2009-paranormal-activity.htm
pn.url<-"http://paranormal.about.com/od/paranormalgeneralinfo/tp/2009-paranormal-activity.htm"
pn.html<-htmlTreeParse(pn.url,useInternalNodes=T)
pn.h3=xpathSApply(pn.html,"//h3",xmlValue)
#extracting the links of the headlines to follow to the story
pn.h3.links=xpathSApply(pn.html,"//h3/a/@href")
#Extracted the links of the Internal structure to follow ...
#Paranormal Activity, Posted 01-03-09 (following this head line)
#http://paranormal.about.com/od/paranormalgeneralinfo/a/news_090314n.htm
pn.l1.url<-pn.h3.links[1]
pn.l1.html<-htmlTreeParse(pn.l1.url,useInternalNodes=T)
pn.l1.links=xpathSApply(pn.l1.html,"//p/a/@href")
#Extracted the links of the Internal structure to follow ...
#British couple has 'black-and-white-twins' twice (following this head line)
#http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/28471626/
pn.l1.f1.url=pn.l1.links[7]
pn.l1.f1.html=htmlTreeParse(pn.l1.f1.url,useInternalNodes=T)
pn.l1.f1.text=xpathSApply(pn.l1.f1.html,"//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)]",xmlValue)
```

I sincerely thanks in advance for reading my post and your time for helping me.
I will be great full for any expert who would like to mentor me in this whole project.

Regards
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) libraries. Despite their being Python based, they are considered the best in scrapping domain. You can use command line interface to connect both, for more details about connecting R and Python have a look [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-into-a-data-analysis-pipeline-part-1/).